# Capturing the email address used in a SLURM batch script

Tags: slurm

I have a SLURM (v19.05.6) batch script :

`test.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --mail-user=First.Last@domain.com
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
env
```

Within my script, I'd like to be able to get email address (i.e. `First.Last@domain.com`) that SLURM uses to mail the user.  I printed out the environment (i.e. `env`) and it is not set as an environmental variable.  Looking at the man page for `sacct` doesn't contain a field for email address either.

**QUESTION** :

How do I get the email address used by SLURM to email users?  In my use case, I'd like to capture that email address and use it in subsequently spawned jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always try to grep it from the job script:

```
MAIL=`grep -m 1 "mail-user=" $0 | cut -d = -f2`
```

the `-m 1` stops grep at the first match and `$0` resolves to the path of the script.

I think it is even my preferred version, as it doesn't need extra communication with the slurmctld. For newer versions (20.02+), you can also parse the output from `scontrol`:

```
MAIL=`scontrol show job ${SLURM_JOB_ID} | grep MailUser |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d = -f 2`
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea.   I'm using v19.05.6, and that information doesn't seem to be stored as mail user.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I don't have a 19.05 cluster available. I'll see if I can think of another way.

Comment: I tried the first command on SLURM 19.05.6 and it worked.  I tried the 2nd command and it worked on our SLURM 20.02.4 system